# How long it takes new Firebase audience to propagate to Remote Config?

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

Created a new audience but do not see it in Remote Config. I'm guessing it takes time to propagate? How long should we expect to wait for it to be ready?

Comment: did you find the reason? still having issues with it